# Animate.css - Animate text sliding in and out

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to achieve having three words which slide in and out seperately. So the first word slides in and out, then the second word slides in and out etc.

How can I achieve this? I tried it with this:

HTML:

```
<p class="fp-animated-subheadline animated"></p>
```

JS:

```
 var texts = ['Bloggers', 'Entrepreneurs', 'Companies'];


    (function () {
      texts.forEach(animateFunction);
    })();


    function animateFunction(item, index) {
        $('.fp-animated-subheadline').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {

            $('.fp-animated-subheadline').html(item);
            $('.fp-animated-subheadline').delay(200).removeClass('fadeInDown');
            $('.fp-animated-subheadline').addClass('fadeOutDown');
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can't use delay for Animate.css as jQuery only uses delay for it'sown animations. You have to use the queue system or SetInterval

Comment: @GaijinJim Do you have an example for using this with aninmate.css?

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery Plugin along with Animate.css [WOW-JS](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)
They have a great documentation also: [Wow-Docs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html)